# how to read and edit a file with .work extension

Tags: windows, command-line, c

I have been using Pollard's kangaroo for SECPK1 and I'm wondering on how to edit the files with .work extension. I googled it and it said I can use Bibble 5 or Coral AfterShot Pro but I cannot open it using these programs so is there a way to open this file and edit it?? Even notepad++ can't read this file!

Comment: Notepadd++ can read any file, even binary files, up to a size limit. How big is your file?

Answer (score 1):

Get a trial version of Ultra Edit (ultraedit.com) and open the file.

It may open as in HEX mode. If not and if you cannot make sense of the file, use the Edit tab in Ultra Edit and select HEX mode (or press Ctrl-H to invoke HEX mode).

HEX mode will show recognizable characters / words on the right.

This method will allow you to open the file and then, possibly make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** open the file and **edit** it, but it will be all gibberish. When you open a file, say a *.pdf*, what your OS does is it sends your file to your default pdf reader, which can properly **read** and interpret your data. You can open and edit a *.pdf* file in notepad, but it is the software which can make sense of it.

So you probably need a software which is able to open the *.work* file.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I edit a Pollard's kangaroo for SECPK1 .work file

These are binary files and not meant to be edited.

You can display some information about the file with the `-winfo` command line option.

Example:

> ```
> Kangaroo.exe -winfo save.work
> Kangaroo v1.5
> Loading: save.work
> Version   : 0
> DP bits   : 16
> Start     : 3447F65ABC9F46F736A95F87B044829C8A0129D56782D635CD00000000000000
> Stop      : 3447F65ABC9F46F736A95F87B044829C8A0129D56782D635CDFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
> Key       : 031D91282433E664132046D25189A5FE0F64645A73494A37AB17BD6FB283AE5BA2
> Count     : 808510464 2^29.591
> Time      : 01:35
> DP Size   : 2.4/5.8MB
> DP Count  : 12199 2^13.574
> HT Max    : 3 [@ 008A9F]
> HT Min    : 0 [@ 000000]
> HT Avg    : 0.05
> HT SDev   : 0.22
> Kangaroos : 4096 2^12.000
> ```

You can also split and merge `.work` files.

Source: [GitHub - JeanLucPons/Kangaroo: Pollard's kangaroo for SECPK1](https://github.com/JeanLucPons/Kangaroo)

Note that the source code is available so could write your own editor that understands the `.work` file format.

Comment: i want to edit the file because i ran the program for for 7 days and accidentally my son deleted the file so i don't want my 7 days work go for waste